# How to handle a virtual path created by proxy server in MVC route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, reverse-proxy

I am fairly new to MVC. Recently I developed a site and hosted it behind a proxy server. I access my site using internalhostname/site/{controller}/{action}/{id} for test, which works fine. 
However, when my users are connecting the site, they would use an external url like this: externalhostname/apps/site/{controller}/{action}/{id}. Now when my views attempt to initiate a call to the controller according to the default route config, the URLs being generated become externalhostname/site/{controller}/{action}/{id}, notice "/apps" is gone.

Well, this is a known problem to me. Because when creating the URL, host name does not include "/apps". In other sites created in regular ASP.NET page, I would simply hijack the URL creation and replace host with host/apps, that can fix the issue. But I don't know how to do this in MVC world.

Also I am using Telerik controls (for MVC) that also initiate requests by controller and action, which lead to the wrong URL eventually.

The route config is default. I did try to change the rule but all of those only affect the url format after . Nothing could allow me to change the behavior ahead of it. 
I have been struggling for days and couldn't see a way out. Appreciate for some advice. Thank you.

I cannot change the proxy rule. That is not an option to me.

Environment: MVC 4, IIS 7.0, if these matter.

Comment: Turned out the problem was outside of the MVC itself. When calling another controller and action inside the controller, it is fine. But when I attempt to call the controller/action from the view using Telerik controls or other HTML controls, it will build the wrong URL. Luckily these controls allow to call the action using absolute URL. I created a method to generate these URLs based on my host name (where I know would introduce this "/apps/" path). This will create the right path for my requests and get to the right controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add new entry in your route config.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default2", // Route name
    "apps/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults,
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Take note of the order.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually tried this and it builds up the URL like this: externalhostname/apps/site/apps/{controller}/{action}/{id}.That didn't help the situation.

Comment: I edited my question a little bit to be more clear. I should not have used angular brackets on some of the words.

Comment: @ChenWang yah a little confusion. now my answer is not valid :)

Comment: Thank you anyway, @Sherlock. I want to correct one thing in my first reply (didn't find a way to edit it). Adding the custom route like this results in a URL like externalhostname/site/apps/{controller}/{action}/{id}. "/apps" gets added after the site name only. It is absolutely correct if I have a virtual path under my site. But it just didn't help in my situation.

Comment: @ChenWang yes your problem now can't be handled by route config. Have you tried to rewrite the URL's?

Comment: Yes, I am looking into that piece right now. If I find anything solid, I will post here.